# There are seven days in a/the week

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

What is correct and why? Both, or only one of the following sentences?

> 1 - There are seven days in **a** week.

-> *One single* week consists of seven days. 1 week = a week = 7 days.

> 2 - There are seven days in **the** week.

-> "The week" as a *general notion*. The only `Week` class for for all the single instances. Having 7 days is a class property, not an instance property.

Similarly:

**A** cat has four legs *or* **The** cat has four legs?

**A** star consists of hot gases *or* **The** star consists of hot gases?

In the last two examples I can imagine also a plural, so **Cats** have four legs *or* **The cats** have four legs?

As for the week, the sentence "**Weeks** have seven days" sounds strange. Why?

Comment: both are correct

Comment: Note that you [can use *the* to indicate a generality](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/117772/18696), but context is important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: PLEASE, all the English native speakers, try to understand that the articles are a very difficult topic for a non-native speaker. Do not mark the question as duplicate just with reference to some more generic answer! For native speakers of languages which do not have / do not need articles it's not so easy as you may feel.

Comment: If anglophones had to justify all the usages of the articles, we'd all speak French.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - you have no clue what pain it is to learn articles for users of languages which do not have such redundant, superfluous, illogical, obstructive things as articles :) Try to imagine you have to artificially add into your sentences some extra words every now and then which you mentally *do not need*, which you do not have in your head when thinking about the ideas you wish to express. And then you ask the native speakers for help and they flag your question as "to be closed", just with a reference to some general answer. This is even more annoying than the articles themselves :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, your analysis is correct. Normally *the* refers to an identified individual or individuals, but it also has a (rather literary) use with generalisations - what you have called class properties.

However, there are more subtleties.

> A cat has four legs *and*
>
> The cat has four legs

both work for the general reading.

But

> The star consists of hot gases.

does not work. This has only a specific reading (a particular star) and not a general reading, at least for me. I *think* this is because general *the* requires a super-class within which to distinguish the items. So (general) *the cat* is distinguished from dogs, horses, etc. But there is no obvious super-class within which stars are just one kind. (This may not be the reason, but it's the best thought I have had).

For the same reason

> There are seven days in the week.

doesn't work for me with a general reading, though my judgment is less clear than for stars.

In your last examples,

> Cats have four legs.

is fine, but

> The cats have four legs.

can only be read as specific cats, not general. General *the* must be singular. *Weeks have seven days* is unusual, but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: +1, but the difference I see between *days in **a** week* and *days in **the** week* is that the former would normally be a simple accounting (the period of time we call a *week* is seven times the length of the period we call a *day*), while the latter would normally be used leading up to an enumeration of the days (and they are called Monday, Tuesday,...). Or, to put it slightly differently, the *a* version refers to a generic week (which could be any of many) while the *the* version refers to the Platonic essence of The Week (of which there is but one).

Comment: @bye - The Platonic essence of The Week - that's exactly my understanding of the *class* notion in object-oriented programming.

Comment: John Lawler (who often comments here) wrote an [answer](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html) which addresses several of your questions, though it doesn't address my question of why _the star consists of hot gases_ doesn't work.

Comment: @ColinFine After long time, I read again the John Lawler's answer http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html you recommended 8 years ago, and still I don't understand why "There are seven days in *the* week" should be wrong. It sounds exactly to me like John's example "The madrigal is polyphonic" (being polyphonic is characteristic of madrigrals) - having 7 days is indeed characteristic of weeks in the same way as having their days named Monday, Tuesday, ... :) And the natural super-class is *unit of time* :) Or would it sound better in "The *Jewish* week has 7 days"?

Answer (score 1):

I can see where the use of "a" and "the" might confuse you if English is your second language.  In the sentences you posed as examples, "the" is used when describing a specific week, while "a" is used when the week could be any week.  Therefore both sentences are correct but have slightly different meanings.  The cat, star, and cats sentences are all correct for the same reason.  As for the sentence "Weeks have seven days" sounding strange to you I have no idea, but it is grammatically correct.

I do not have a degree in English, but I was blessed with a grandmother who taught college level English, and lovingly corrected my grammar in my childhood.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said --

1. *There are seven days in **a week**.*
2. *The seven days of **the week** are Monday, Tuesday,...*

In (1), the statement is about an arbitrary week: For all *x* such that *x* is a week, *x* has seven days.

In (2), the statement is about the general concept *week*: It is defined as a sequence of these seven days: Monday, Tuesday,....